# how to disable draggable div when scroll bar is focused on in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, scrollbar, draggable

I have a jQuery draggable container div with a side scroll bar that should not be draggable when I am scrolling up and down.  .infotext is the inner div that has the text, contained within #infobody which is set to overflow:auto.  I need a way to negate the draggable function on the div when the scrollbar is selected.  Here is my code:

```
$(".lsidebar").draggable({"scroll":false});

 .lsidebar #infobody{
cursor:default;
position:absolute;
width:100%;
overflow:auto;
margin:23px 0 0 0;
z-index:14;
}

   #infobody .infotext{
cursor:default;
position:relative;
width:100%;
z-index:14;
color:#969696;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A workaround to this problem (because for some reason no one is answering my questions as of recently) was to substitute the default browser scrollbar with a jQuery scrollbar known as jScrollPane. Doing this allows me to use the inserted scrollbar ID as a selector to disable draggable...like so:

```
 $('.jScrollPaneDrag').live('mousedown mouseup', function(e){
     if(e.type=='mousedown'){
         $('.lsidebar').draggable({disable: true});
     }else{
         $('.lsidebar').draggable({"scroll":false});
     };
 });
```

Answer (score 11):

Actually you can use "cancel" property in draggable to prevent the scrolling event affect to the draggable element.

For example:

if your html is like this...

```
<div class="draggable">
    <div class="scrollable"></div>
</div>
```

for the js:

```
$('.draggable').draggable({
   cancel: '.scrollable'
});
```

When you scrolling in that specific area, the outer draggable element will be temporary disabled.

Comment: +1 - presumably this feature didn't exist when OP asked the question, but definitely the right answer now.

Answer (score 3):

this works for me, im using jquery ui 1.8.2.

```
      $(".drag").draggable({
                        start: function(e, ui) {
                        if ($(e.originalEvent.target).is(".scroll"))
                            e.preventDefault();
                        }
                    })
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess this might work fine

```
$("div")
.mouseenter(function(){...bind drag;})
.mouseleave(function(){...unbind drag;});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `overflow:hidden;` in the css of the page_wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind to the scroll event on the current element and all its children and parents as done below, the dragging will be disabled while scrolling on:

- Current draggable element
- All children of the draggable element
- All draggable parents of the draggable element

check this [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Salihane/bh6h8xjo/).

```
$(function () {
    $(".draggable").draggable({
        start: function () {
            // cancel draggin while scrolling
            if ($(this).data("scrolled")) {
                $(this).data("scrolled", false).trigger("mouseup");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }).find("*").andSelf().scroll(function () {
        // Bind to the scroll event on current element, and all its children.

        // Prevent all draggable parents from dragging while they are scrolling
        $(this).parents(".ui-draggable").data("scrolled", true);
    }); });
```