# how to disable draggable div when child element scrollbar is being used

Tags: jquery, scrollbar, draggable

I have a jQuery draggable container div with a side scroll bar that should not be draggable when I am scrolling up and down.  .infotext is the inner div that has the text, contained within #infobody which is set to overflow:auto.  I need a way to negate the draggable function on the parent div when the child scrollbar is selected.  Here is my code:

```
$(".lsidebar").draggable({"scroll":false});

 .lsidebar #infobody{
cursor:default;
position:absolute;
width:100%;
overflow:auto;
margin:23px 0 0 0;
z-index:14;
}

   #infobody .infotext{
cursor:default;
position:relative;
width:100%;
z-index:14;
color:#969696;
}
```

Comment: I suggest you delete this question as the other one you asked has more answers and also includes yours. :D http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3300765/how-to-disable-draggable-div-when-scroll-bar-is-focused-on-in-jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A workaround to this problem (because for some reason no one is answering my questions as of recently) was to substitute the default browser scrollbar with a jQuery scrollbar known as jScrollPane.  Doing this allows me to use the  inserted scrollbar ID as a selector to disable draggable...like so:

```
$('.jScrollPaneDrag').live('mousedown mouseup', function(e){
  if(e.type=='mousedown'){
      $('.lsidebar').draggable({disable: true});
  }else{
     $('.lsidebar').draggable({"scroll":false});
  };
```

});